# Why in Midnight Commander the chmod has 5 digits and what for?

Tags: chmod, midnight-commander

In the file menu if I go to chmod, it returnes the chmod value for the folder / file.

I understand the last 3 digits, the second is setuid/setgid/sticky bit (have read the docs on it but its use is not that clear to me)... and then there is the first digit which I guess is for file/folder and what else? Like for a folder the digit is 4, for file 0... what about the 2 and 6? I checked that the symbolic link doesn't have a separate chmod first digit value.

Comment: Can you provide the actual text from the documentation that describes ths feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod`, as you probably know, is short for “change mode”.  “mode” here refers to the `st_mode` field in the inode.  [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html), the man page for the `stat`, `fstat`, and `lstat` system calls, shows *st_mode* values of up to seven digits.  Here’s an excerpt:

> **`S_IFSOCK`**   `0140000   socket`
>      **`S_IFLNK`**    `0120000   symbolic link`
>      **`S_IFREG`**    `0100000   regular file`
>      **`S_IFBLK`**    `0060000   block device`
>      **`S_IFDIR`**    `0040000   directory`
>      **`S_IFCHR`**    `0020000   character device`
>      **`S_IFIFO`**    `0010000   FIFO`

OK, the first digit is always zero, to indicate that the number is octal; we can ignore that.  MC seems to be ignoring the second one too.  So you can see that regular files have 0 for the third (i.e., the fifth from the right) digit, and directories have 4.   2 and 6 are character device and block device, respectively; you should see these only in `/dev`.  Named pipes should be 1, and file system sockets should be 4.    If symbolic links are displaying as 0, that’s odd; maybe somebody thought that displaying 2 would be too confusing.